# Was the F-4 Phantom the only fighter to be in service for the US Navy, Air Force and Marines?

Tags: military, usa, aviation-history, fighter, f-4

As is stated [here](http://nationalinterest.org/blog/the-buzz/americas-f-4-phantom-taking-the-world-best-fighters-almost-16738):

> Furthermore, the F-4 came in both ground- and carrier-based models and
>   served in the U.S. Air Force, Navy and Marines. The only other
>   frontline fighter to serve in all three services before or since is
>   the F-35.

Is that correct? Was any other fighter used by all three services?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is accurate.

Answer (score 8):

The statement is accurate.

[Here is a list of all U.S. Fighter Aircraft, in service and retired on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_aircraft_of_the_United_States#Fighter). The following is an excerpt from that list for relevant aircraft.

- [F-4 Phantom (Air Force/Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II)
- [F-5 Freedom Fighter (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_F-5_Freedom_Fighter)
- [F-6 Skyray (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_F4D_Skyray)
- [F-7 Sea Dart (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_F2Y_Sea_Dart)
- [F-8 Crusader (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_F-8_Crusader)
- [F-9 Cougar (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F9F_Cougar)
- [F-10 Skynight (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_F3D_Skyknight)
- [F-11 Tiger (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F11F_Tiger)
- [F-12 Lockheed (Air Force, A12 Variant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-12)
- [F-14 Tomcat (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F-14_Tomcat)
- [F-15 Eagle/Strike Eagle (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-15_Eagle)
- [F-16 Fighting Falcon (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16_Fighting_Falcon)
- [F-17 Cobra (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_F-17_Cobra)
- [F-117 Nighthawk (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-117A_Nighthawk)
- [F-18 Hornet/Super Hornet (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet)
- [F-20 Tigershark (Prototype, cancelled)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_F-20_Tigershark)
- [F-21 Kfir C-2 (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAI_Kfir)
- [F-22 Raptor (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor)
- [F-23 Black Widow II (Air Force, cancelled)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_YF-23)
- [F-35 Lightning II (Navy/Marine Corps/Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II)
- [F/P-80 Shooting Star (Air Force/Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-80_Shooting_Star)
- [FH-1 Phantom (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_FH_Phantom)
- [F2H Banshee (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_F2H_Banshee)
- [FJ-1 Fury (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_FJ-1_Fury)
- [F-86 Sabre/Super Sabre (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-86_Sabre)
- [F-82 Twin Mustang (USAF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-82_Twin_Mustang)
- [F7U Cutlass (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_F7U_Cutlass)
- [F-102 Delta Dagger (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_F-102_Delta_Dagger)
- [F-106 Delta Dart (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_F-106_Delta_Dart)
- [F-104 Starfighter (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter)
- [F-101 Voodoo (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_F-101_Voodoo)
- [F3H Demon (Navy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_F3H_Demon)
- [FJ-2/FJ-3 Fury (Navy/Marines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_FJ-2/-3_Fury)
- [F-89 Scorpion (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_F-89_Scorpion)
- [F-84 Thunderstreak (Air Force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_F-84F_Thunderstreak)

This list includes fighter aircraft introduced or in service after 1949, when the US Air Force was created until the end of 1960 when the F-4 Phantom came into service.

Table image was removed because the data is out-of-date. You can view the [original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h526T.png).

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks.

Comment: Anything in the A series that would fit? The table is wrong btw, the F-17 was cancelled, the F-20 was never considered, the F-12 only existed on paper. There were 2 different aircraft called the A-12, one CIA (though with AF markings, and the other a cancelled Navy aircraft of a completely different type).

Comment: And yet, given all the problems they experienced with the F-4, someone still thought a one-size-fits-all aircraft was a good idea... *sigh*...

Comment: @HephaestusAetnaean the YF-17 became the F/A-18. It's the same plane more-or-less... YF-17 was the prototype.

Comment: @SnakeDoc - YF-17 was a prototype for the [never realized] F-17 and lost to the F-16 in the USAF LWF program. MD and Northrop then heavily modified it to become the F-18, adding 2,000 lbs to the empty weight (and another 9,000 lbs for the later Super Hornet). The YF-17 and F-18A/C look very similar, but are distinct a/c built for different services.

Comment: @HephaestusAetnaean Yes, and saying the YF-17 lost to the F-18 isn't correct... the YF-17 was revised into the F-18. The Navy had slightly different priorities in design, but the YF-17 wasn't thrown out and the F-18 done from scratch...

Comment: @SnakeDoc - `Yes, and saying the YF-17 lost to the F-18 isn't correct` Well, of course... the YF-17 lost the LWF competition before the F-18 even existed. Someone would have to be awful silly to make that kinda typo, dontcha think? [and of course I delete the wrong comment...]

Comment: There was no F-17. The **Y**F-17 lost to the F-1**6** (only 2 built). The F-22 and YF-23 both had proposed naval variants. Neither left the drawing board though. If the F-20 and "F"-23 make that list though, you may as well include the "F"-32 and naval F-111B.

Comment: `Here is a list of ALL U.S. Fighter Aircraft, in service and retired` - the US made dozens more fighters, from WWII props, to early jets, to the century series.

Comment: @HephaestusAetnaean The question specifically identifies the **Air Force** not the Army Air Corps. The Air Force never operated a piston fighter. The list I posted, if you scroll up or down, actually includes **every** aircraft in service or retired, the reference in my post is about the link, not the information in this post. I did miss some aircraft though, updating now.

Comment: Your blanket USAF piston fighter claim is wrong.  The USAF separated in 1947 still early in the jet transition, and it operated F-51D's in Korea until at least 1953.

Comment: Doesn't change the answer, but that list from Wikipedia missed the fact that the USN operated F-16's as Top Gun adversary aircraft. According to a friend who flew them, they were the best-performing F-16's because they were optimized for air-to-air and left off equipment (i.e. weight) that was only used for air-to-ground.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not technically a fighter, but the A-1 Skyraider was (in different variants, like the F-4) also used by all services.

It was even used in air to air combat, shooting down at least one North Korean and one Chinese aircraft during the Korean war and several North Vietnamese MiGs during the Vietnam war.

Not sure if that makes it a fighter according to whatever definition you're using.

Answer (score 3):

The FJ Fury is actually a Navy/Marine derivative of the Air Force F-86 Sabre.
Variants of the Northrup F-5 were also used by all services, although mostly in adversary training roles. The A-7 was used by the Navy and Air Force, but I don't think the Marines ever flew them (fighter?).
And going back further, and in the non-fighter category, the B-24 had a Navy variant in the PB4Y--not Marines again.

Comment: A-7 was indeed never used by the Marines. They stayed with the A-1 longer in the close air support role, and A-6 and F-4 variants for bombing missions.